# How to remove empty key value pair from dictionary in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

Lets say I have a dictionary

```
let dic = ["a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "", "d": "3"]
```

I want to delete "c" key with its value

Comment: you have to use `var` instead of `let` if you want to mutate it.

Comment: then `dic.removeValue(forKey: "c")`

Comment: @LeoDabus, in that case you may propose to replace `let dic = ["a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "", "d": "3"]` with `let dic = ["a": "1", "b": "2", "d": "3"]` /s. Question asks how to remove pair that falls for **specific condition (value is empty [string])**, not how to remove value with key `"c"`. Or any other specific key.

Comment: @user28434 last sentence in the post **I want to delete “c” key with its value.**

Comment: @LeoDabus which could be interpreted as the expected outcome of removing all empty values. I think we all can agree that this question can be read in different ways...

Comment: @LeoDabus, and first say `Lets say`. So the body of the question is just an example of the dictionary, and which key pair qualifies for being `empty`. Essense is in the title.

Answer (score 4):

This should do.

```
let dic = ["a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "", "d": "3"]

let filteredDict = dic.filter( { !$0.value.isEmpty })
print(filteredDict) // Prints ["a": "1", "b": "2", "d": "3"]
```

**Edit:** David's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53652833/7734643) is the one you go for if you only want to delete a specific key. But that makes no sense because if you knew what key to delete, would it matter if it is empty or not? I am assuming that you **do not know** which key(s) is empty, in which case you would have to do like how it is shown in this answer.

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked. The question simply asks how to delete one specific key. There is nothing in the question that asks how to remove all key/value pairs where the value is the empty string.

Comment: @rmaddy, you mean, except the title?

Comment: @user28434 Ha! Silly me. I was reading the question, not the title.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative using filter with a `forEach` loop that updates the original dictionary:

```
var dic = ["a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "", "d": "3"]

dic.filter({$0.value.isEmpty}).forEach( { dic[$0.key] = nil})
```

Answer (score -2):

You just need to set the value of the key you want to remove to `nil`. Just make sure that you declare the dictionary as mutable using the `var` keyword.

```
var dic = ["a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "", "d": "3"]
dic["c"] = nil
print(dic) //["a": "1", "b": "2", "d": "3"]
```

Note: This doesn't work if `Value` is optional.

Comment: What if he has multiple key value pairs which have empty string values?

Comment: That's too ad-hoc solution. And assumes that dictionary data is static and/or predefined before compilation.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri The question says nothing about deleting all keys where its value is blank. The question simply asks how to remove one specific key.

Comment: @rmaddy At present it looks like that because on top of asking the question, he gives a very specific example. I made a guess that he probably wants to delete all the empty ones. We'll wait for OP to clarify. P.S - i did not downvote.

Comment: @user28434 this is exactly what the question was asking for. How to delete a specific key-value pair from a `Dictionary`.

Comment: I think title implies that the dictionary and `"c"` here are just for example. Question asks how to remove **empty key-value pair**, so it should work for any **empty key-value pair**(it should be `key-value pair with empty string as value` though), not for specific key in specific dictionary.

Comment: @user28434 did you actually read the question? It explicitly says: _"I want to delete "c" key with its value"_. It doesn't talk about an empty key-value pair, it mentions a specific key-value pair.

Comment: If the question was 'How to greet user?'/'Lets say `username` is "John". How do I print out "Hello, John"?' Will your answer will be `print("Hello, John")` or `print("Hello, \(username)")`?